# java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have looked at other stackoverflow threads to get an answer for this problem.  Mostly what I see is that it is caused by typos, although I cannot see any in this method.  This method is called from another method in the same class and when run returns the error :

java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1

The code for my class is here:

```
public void WriteTag(String tagPrefix, String tagName, String tagContent)
{
    try {
        String query = String.format("INSERT INTO %s(%s,%s) VALUES(?,?)", 
                tagPrefix, TAGNAME_COLUMN, TAGCONTENT_COLUMN);
        PreparedStatement sqlStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        sqlStatement.setString(1, tagName);
        sqlStatement.setString(2, tagContent);
        //sqlStatement.executeUpdate();
    } catch(Exception e) {HandleException(e);}
}
```

I'm not really sure what is wrong here.  The constants are properly defined elsewhere in the code.  Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The code looks fine. Probably the error is somewhere else or you're not running the code you're seeing.

Comment: Are you sure the version executing is the same as the source you're viewing?

Comment: My first port of call would be to replace the constants with hard coded column names and see if that cures the problem. As the others are saying, on the face of it, this code looks OK.

Comment: Thanks, hard-coding the column names got rid of that error.

Comment: This code does not produce this exception, as `executeUpdate()` is not executed, and it is the only statement here that can produce that exception. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String query = "Insert into foo (foo1,foo2) Values (?,?)";
PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
pst.setString(1, whatever);
pst.setString(2, whatever);
pst.executeUpdate();  // this is actually important in order to get data inserted into database.
```

So technically hardcode the tablenames that are in the databse. and it should work.

Comment: Why? What evidence do you have that this will solve the problem as opposed to the OP's code?

Comment: I would prefer the table and column names hardcoded myself, but I can't see why having them as parameters would affect the execution, or produce the exception.